# Remove rows corresponding to last subgroup in each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have the following DataFrame

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['eggs', np.nan, 'ham', 'eggs', 'spam', 'spam',
                   'eggs', 'spam', np.nan], columns=['ingredients'])
df['customer'] = (['Badger']*3 + ['Shopkeeper']*3 + ['Pepperpots']*2
    + [np.nan])
df['ordered'] = [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, np.nan]
df.sort_values(['customer', 'ingredients'], inplace=True)
```

which looks like this:

```
  ingredients    customer  ordered
0        eggs      Badger      1.0
2         ham      Badger      0.0
1         NaN      Badger      1.0
6        eggs  Pepperpots      1.0
7        spam  Pepperpots      0.0
3        eggs  Shopkeeper      0.0
4        spam  Shopkeeper      1.0
5        spam  Shopkeeper      0.0
8         NaN         NaN      NaN
```

For each customer, I would like to remove rows corresponding to the last ingredient (according to alphabetical order).

So for example, rows indexed by 4 and 5 should be removed, because they correspond to Shopkeeper's last ingredient.

Similarly, row 7 should be removed, because it corresponds to Pepperpots' last ingredient.

`NaN` values should be ignored.

Comment: What about row indexed with `2`? And I'm guessing `NaN` is omitted from removal?

Comment: `ham` is removed for `Badger` ?

Comment: Yes - edited, I'm sorry for having asked the question ambiguously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) which by default omit `NaN`s values with filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = df['ingredients'].groupby(df['customer']).transform('last')
df = df[df['ingredients'] != s]
print (df)
  ingredients    customer  ordered
0        eggs      Badger      1.0
1         NaN      Badger      1.0
6        eggs  Pepperpots      1.0
3        eggs  Shopkeeper      0.0
8         NaN         NaN      NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a series consisting of groupwise "last" ingredients, then filter these out. Note, for this purpose, that `NaN` ingredients don't get removed.

```
s = df.sort_values('ingredients')\
      .groupby('customer')['ingredients']\
      .transform('last').sort_index()

df = df[df['ingredients'] != s]

print(df)

  ingredients    customer  ordered
0        eggs      Badger      1.0
1         NaN      Badger      1.0
3        eggs  Shopkeeper      0.0
6        eggs  Pepperpots      1.0
8         NaN         NaN      NaN
```

With this solution, you can omit `df.sort_values(['customer', 'ingredients'], inplace=True)`, as `GroupBy` + `transform` as implemented above aligns by index.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, jpp!